# useEffect + redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook

когда в зависимости пустой массив,рендер только раз.
Когда добавляю на сервер пост,чтобы его увидеть , нужно перезагрузить страницу.
Когда ставлю зависимость, бесконечный  цикл.
Прошу помощи.
Буду благодарен, за разъяснение!)

```
const Posts = () => {
    const {posts} = useSelector(state => ({posts: state.postsPage.posts}))
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
   



    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPost())
    },[])


    return <>
        <h1>Posts Lists</h1>
        <PostsForm/>
        {posts.map(post  => <Post key={post.key} title={post.title} id={post.id} body={post.body} />)}
    </>
}

export default Posts;
```

Comment: массив зависимостей должен быть пуст и все далжно работать идеально вот так как ты написал

Comment: оно работает,но мне не нравится ,чтобы увидеть посты которые я добавил,нужно нажимать ф5.
Даже когда делаешь редирект,думал хоть это поможет.
Это может быть проблема в сервере?

Answer (score 1):

```
//тут useSelector
const [x, setX] = useState([1,2,3])

useEffect(() => {
//тут твой диспатч
    setTimeout(() => {
        setX((prev) => {
            return [
                ...prev,
                4
            ]
        })
    },2000)
    
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`object22222222222222222222222222`);
},[x])
return (
    <div>
        {x}
    </div>
)
```

по идее должно работать просто добавь втарой useEffect